# How do I add a background image on a JFrame using a JLabel?

Tags: java, jframe, bluej

I am trying to display a background image on the JFrame using a JLabel. The code runs and the buttons appear, but the image does not. I have researched for solutions, yet I have not found one for my code specifically. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
/**
 * Adds details to interface and programs buttons
 * 
 * Imani Davis 
 * Final Project
 */

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;


public class Use_PF_Interface extends JFrame implements Pet_Fish_Interface
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private JFrame window;
    private JPanel panel1, panel2, panel3;
    private JLabel lblBackgroundImage = new JLabel();
    private JButton feedButton = new JButton("Feed Fish");
    private JButton playGamesButton = new JButton("Play Game");

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Use_PF_Interface
     */
    public Use_PF_Interface()
    {
        setTitle("Virtual Pet Fish");
        setSize(650, 650);


        //initializes panels and panel layout
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel3 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel3.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        lblBackgroundImage.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        //sets background image of panel
        lblBackgroundImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\This PC\\Desktop\\OCEAN2.JPEG"));
        panel1.add(lblBackgroundImage);
        validate();

        //adds button to panels
        panel2.add(feedButton);
        panel2.add(playGamesButton);

        //add panels to frame
        add(panel1);
        add(panel2);

    }


}
```

Comment: You are adding panel1 and then panel2, panel2 is placed above the panel1 and so your panel1 is not visible and hence the image is not visible.

Answer (score 2):

`JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` by default, a `BorderLayout` can only manage a single component within any of the five available positions it provides, this means that `panel2` is most likely the only component getting shown.

An alternative is to add you components to the `JLabel`, but remember, `JLabel` doesn't have a default layout manager.  Also, remember, `JLabel` only uses the `icon` and `text` properties to calculate its preferred size, so if the contents require more space, they will be clipped.

Start by having a look at [How to Use BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more details

Also, remember, most Swing components are opaque generally, so you need to set them transparent when you want to do something like this

[image: Background]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Use_PF_Interface extends JFrame {
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own

    private JPanel panel2;
    private JLabel lblBackgroundImage = new JLabel();
    private JButton feedButton = new JButton("Feed Fish");
    private JButton playGamesButton = new JButton("Play Game");

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Use_PF_Interface
     */
    public Use_PF_Interface() {
        setTitle("Virtual Pet Fish");
        setSize(650, 650);

        //initializes panels and panel layout
        panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setOpaque(false);
        panel2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        lblBackgroundImage.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        //sets background image of panel
        lblBackgroundImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon("..."));
        lblBackgroundImage.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //adds button to panels
        panel2.add(feedButton);
        panel2.add(playGamesButton);

        lblBackgroundImage.add(panel2);

        add(lblBackgroundImage);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new Use_PF_Interface();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: but how if I want to locate the buttons in a specific location in the Frame?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ImageInFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String path = "Image1.jpg";
        File file = new File(path);
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(label);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocation(200,200);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: but how to add buttons ... they won't appear!

Comment: How do make the image remain the same size as the frame, and resize with it? Also, like @Yahya said, any components we add aren't shown.